Filtration of U(g)
Let $g$ be a f.d. simple Lie algebra (say over $\mathbb{C}$) and $U(g)$ its universal enveloping algebra. What can be said about $U(g)$ viewed as the regular left $U(g)$-module? Is there a nice decreasing filtration $\{ U(g)_i \}_{i \geq 0}$ with $U(g)_0=U(g)$ so that $U(g)_{i}/U(g)_{i+1}$ is direct sum of simple g-modules?
